# Getting javax.ejb.EJBException when trying to add client into db

Tags: jpa, ejb

im doing web application using java ee, sqlserver database. im trying to add new client into a db using entitymanager and im getting such an exception. Server (glassfish) runs with no errors

```
[2018-11-09T13:20:33.396+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [AS-EJB-00056] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1541766033396] [levelValue: 900] [[
  A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB KontoBean, method: public void rental.KontoBean.addNewClient(rental.DaneLogowaniaEntity,rental.DaneKlientEntity,rental.KlientEntity)]]

[2018-11-09T13:20:33.397+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1541766033397] [levelValue: 900] [[

javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:752)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:702)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy212.addNewClient(Unknown Source)
    at rental.__EJB31_Generated__KontoBean__Intf____Bean__.addNewClient(Unknown Source)
    at rental.KontoNamed.addNewKlientEntity(KontoNamed.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.init(EntityManagerWrapper.java:138)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.doTxRequiredCheck(EntityManagerWrapper.java:158)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.doTransactionScopedTxCheck(EntityManagerWrapper.java:151)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:281)
    at rental.KontoBean.addNewClient(KontoBean.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 50 more
]]

[2018-11-09T13:20:33.401+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1541766033401] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:752)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:702)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy212.addNewClient(Unknown Source)
    at rental.__EJB31_Generated__KontoBean__Intf____Bean__.addNewClient(Unknown Source)
    at rental.KontoNamed.addNewKlientEntity(KontoNamed.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.init(EntityManagerWrapper.java:138)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.doTxRequiredCheck(EntityManagerWrapper.java:158)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.doTransactionScopedTxCheck(EntityManagerWrapper.java:151)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:281)
    at rental.KontoBean.addNewClient(KontoBean.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java]]

[2018-11-09T13:20:33.401+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1541766033401] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  :212)
    ... 50 more]]
```

My KlientEntity.java

```
package rental;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Klient", schema = "dbo", catalog = "Test")
public class KlientEntity {
    private int id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID",nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private DaneKlientEntity daneKlientEntity;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private DaneLogowaniaEntity daneLogowaniaEntity;



    public DaneKlientEntity getDaneKlientEntity() {
        return daneKlientEntity;
    }

    public void setDaneKlientEntity(DaneKlientEntity daneKlientEntity) {
        this.daneKlientEntity = daneKlientEntity;
    }

    public DaneLogowaniaEntity getDaneLogowaniaEntity() {
        return daneLogowaniaEntity;
    }

    public void setDaneLogowaniaEntity(DaneLogowaniaEntity daneLogowaniaEntity) {
        this.daneLogowaniaEntity = daneLogowaniaEntity;
    }
}
```

KontoBean.java

```
package rental;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

@LocalBean
@Stateless
public class KontoBean {

    public KontoBean(){

    }
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public void addNewClient(DaneLogowaniaEntity daneLogowaniaEntity, DaneKlientEntity daneKlientEntity, KlientEntity klientEntity) {

        entityManager.persist(daneLogowaniaEntity);
        entityManager.persist(daneKlientEntity);
        entityManager.persist(klientEntity);
        entityManager.flush();
    }
    public void updateDaneKlientaEntity(DaneKlientEntity daneKlientEntity)
    {
        DaneKlientEntity entity = entityManager.find(DaneKlientEntity.class,daneKlientEntity.getId());
        entity.setEmail(daneKlientEntity.getEmail());
        entity.setImie(daneKlientEntity.getImie());
        entity.setNazwisko(daneKlientEntity.getNazwisko());
        entity.setTel(daneKlientEntity.getTel());
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }

    public void updateDaneLogowaniaEntity(DaneLogowaniaEntity daneLogowaniaEntity)
    {
        DaneLogowaniaEntity daneLogowaniaEntity1 = entityManager.find(DaneLogowaniaEntity.class,daneLogowaniaEntity.getId());
    }
    public void updateKlientEntity(DaneKlientEntity daneKlientEntity, DaneLogowaniaEntity daneLogowaniaEntity)
    {
        updateDaneKlientaEntity(daneKlientEntity);
        updateDaneLogowaniaEntity(daneLogowaniaEntity);
    }
}
```

KontoNamed.java

```
package rental;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;


@Named("kontoNamed")
public class KontoNamed {
    private String verificationPassword;
    @EJB
    private MessageBean messageBean;
    public String getMessageBean() {return messageBean.getContent();}
    @EJB
    KontoBean kontoBean;

    KlientEntity klientEntity = new KlientEntity();
    DaneLogowaniaEntity daneLogowaniaEntity = new DaneLogowaniaEntity();
    DaneKlientEntity daneKlientEntity = new DaneKlientEntity();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        klientEntity = new KlientEntity();
        klientEntity.setDaneLogowaniaEntity(new DaneLogowaniaEntity());
        klientEntity.setDaneKlientEntity(new DaneKlientEntity());
    }

    public KlientEntity getKlientEntity(){return klientEntity;}
    public void setKlientEntity(KlientEntity klientEntity){this.klientEntity=klientEntity;}

    public DaneKlientEntity getDaneKlientEntity(){return daneKlientEntity;}
    public void setDaneKlientEntity(DaneKlientEntity daneKlientEntity){this.daneKlientEntity=daneKlientEntity;}

    public DaneLogowaniaEntity getDaneLogowaniaEntity(){return daneLogowaniaEntity;}
    public void setDaneLogowaniaEntity(DaneLogowaniaEntity daneLogowaniaEntity){this.daneLogowaniaEntity=daneLogowaniaEntity;}
    public void addNewKlientEntity() {
            klientEntity.setDaneKlientEntity(daneKlientEntity);
            klientEntity.setDaneLogowaniaEntity(daneLogowaniaEntity);
            try {
                kontoBean.addNewClient(daneLogowaniaEntity, daneKlientEntity, klientEntity);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                messageBean.setContent("Błąd przy dodawaniu nowego konta!");
                return;
            }
            messageBean.setContent("Dodanie rekordu zakończone sukcesem!");
    }
    public String getVerificationPassword(){return verificationPassword;}
    public void setVerificationPassword(String verificationPassword) {
        this.verificationPassword = verificationPassword;
    }
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
        <class>rental.AdminEntity</class>
        <class>rental.DaneKlientEntity</class>
        <class>rental.DaneLogowaniaEntity</class>
        <class>rental.KlientEntity</class>
        <class>rental.NaprawyEntity</class>
        <class>rental.PunktEntity</class>
        <class>rental.RaportyEntity</class>
        <class>rental.RowerEntity</class>
        <class>rental.WypozyczenieEntity</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=Test"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="baza"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="03c8bb23"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Exception shows when i click add button on webpage,

Comment: The stacktrace contains an explicit error. Please search on that and improve your title (and the question is not jsf related)

Answer (score 0):

You must define connection pool and JDBC resource in glassfish. and use it(it's JNDI name) at the jta-data-sourc tag.

```
    <persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">  
        <jta-data-source>[your JNDI name]</jta-data-source>
```

the following link describes the process of defining the connection pool
https://dzone.com/articles/jdbc-connection-pool-for-glassfish-and-payara-java

you do not need to define the database connection properties in persistence.xml

the following lines are not necessary

```
 <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=Test"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="baza"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="03c8bb23"/>

        </properties>
```

you also must change the injection point of EntityManager

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "NewPersistenceUnit")
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, id did all this things but problem is not solved.Still got ejb exceptions

Comment: probably the JDBC source definition in Glassfish or JNDI name is not correct. pls double check

Comment: i think its ok, ping in glassfish configuration pool was working. i will do tomorrow some screenshots.

Comment: Problem solved. Had perstitence.xml in wrong directory. Instead of src/java/resources/meta-inf ive got in src/java/meta-inf. Thanks for answers